# How to get records in tree view from mysql / php

Tags: php, mysql, treeview, mysqli

I have to create a tree view from the records of my table below

```
id user_id friend_id property_id
1    123       321          1
2    123       456          1
3    456       909          1
4    909       222          1
```

I have the user_id i.e 123 and property_id i.e 1 I need to know how can I make a tree with friends with whom I share this property, and afterwards with users with whom my friends share this ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok since there are several steps I'll start out on a high level. If you need help with any of those, ask again!

First of all, you'll need the "root" nodes, ie those users who don't appear as children in the friend column.

Then, for each of these users, start polling all their children. For this, define a function that gets all the children of a user and which calls itself recursively for the children of the child it finds.

This is pretty abstract, because the question is what you want to do with this structure. This depends on the last part, your presentation layer. That's what I know least about; there may be a framework which helps you visualize trees in PHP, but I don't know. There will typically be some sort of object structure with layout properties and child objects; instantiate those properties in your recursive function from the last step.

As a side node, it isn't clear if the data structure you obtain is actually a tree. If you are A, have friends B and C, and C is also a friend of B, B will show up as your friend (on level 2 of the tree) and as C's friend (on level 3). You'll have to check what's your desired behaviour in that spot and might have to, e.g., ignore C the second time you encounter it.

Comment: Yes I get it working through recursive function but that is not what I prefer to do. What I was thinking that I pass just the root node id(user_id) and the property_id and it return a tree in array form? Is it possible?

Comment: you can represent a tree as an array, see the array representation of a Heap, for example. You can also rewrite any recursive function as a non-recursive one using a stack (since recursive function calls are basically just syntactic sugar aroung stack operations). Both probably increases the complexity of your code.

Comment: However. If you only want to go to two levels (your friends, their friends), you might be doing fine just creating a function that returns the immediate list of children. Then go over all these children and call the function again to get your friends' friends. Since you're not interested in deeper levels, that actually sounds like a good idea. Where are you stuck then, with this approach?

Comment: I have to go to n-levels what I made is a recursive function that call itself to generate nodes. I want to know is this approach works when the tree goes to i.e 10 levels? Actually I am afraid that can it become a burden for my database to call recursive functions?

Comment: nah don't worry. I mean you may run into memory or run-time complexity issues, but this doesn't depend on recursive or non-recursive querying. Just make sure the fields you're looking up are indexed or it's gonna get very slow over time as the user base grows